# How to capture signature pad image in a PHP file and output into an HTML file like a receipt and then store the page as JPEG or PDF

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I am using Thomas J. Bradley's signature pad to apply customer's signatures to a receipt page but his tutorial isn't complete and leaves you with a PHP page of just the signature and no description on how to apply it in your next page. It just stops on the output page with just the signature image by itself. I want to apply it inside a receipt HTML page I've already built under the product information and then send a screenshot of the page as an email to basically store the receipt on my computer. Here is where I am at with it.

Signature Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex" />
<meta name="googlebot-news" content="noindex" />
<title>Signature</title>
<style type="text/css">
.disclaimerific {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style10 {
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
<link href="assets/jquery.signaturepad.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="assets/flashcanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" /> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />


        <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #DDDDDD">

<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 799px">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0">
        <img alt="" height="27" src="http://www.themidaslegacy.com/images2/headerml.jpg" width="800" /></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <div align="center">
                <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <div class="auto-style10" style="text-align:center;">
                            <font size="6" color="#CC0000" face="Impact">Please sign below. </font>
                        </div>
                        <p class="auto-style10" style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;"><font face="Arial">***After you submit your signature it will be applied to your receipt on the next page.*** <br>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Signature Table Box -->
                <div style="width:450px; height:auto;  margin: 0px auto 50px; auto; padding:20px; color:black;" >

                     <form method="post" action="capture_signature.php" class="sigPad">

                        <p class="drawItDesc">Draw your signature</p>

                        <div class="sig sigWrapper">
                          <canvas class="pad" width="400"></canvas>

                          <input type="hidden" name="output" class="output">
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div style="width:100%;">
                            <style>

                                </style>
                            <table style="width: 100%;text-align: center;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 50%;">
                                     <div id="submit" >
                                        <button id="btn-accept" style="width: 100%;color:white;" href="" type="submit" class="button1"><p style="font-size: 14px;">Accept Agreement.</p></button>
                                    </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 50%;">
                                    <div id="clear" >
                                        <button style="width: 100%;" href="" name="clear" type="clear" class="clearButton"><p style="font-size: 14px;">Clear Signature</p></button>
                                    </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!-- <div style="clear:both;"></div> -->
                      </form>

                </div>
                        <script src="assets/flashcanvas.js"></script>
                         <script src="assets/jquery.signaturepad.js"></script>
                          <script src="assets/json2.min.js"></script>
                          <script src="assets/functions.js"></script>

        <!-- End Signature Table Box -->

    </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #dddddd">
        <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #dddddd; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:9px; color:#666">
        <div align="center">
        <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0">&nbsp;<img alt="" height="36" src="../images2/contactfooter.jpg" width="557" /><br />
        <br />
      </div></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #dddddd; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:9px; color:#666"><div align="center">
        <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0">&copy; Copyright TML Group, LLC.<br />
        </div></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="2" style="background-color: #dddddd"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
        <div align="center" style="width:750px; color:#666666"  >
            <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"></div>
<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td style="text-align: center"></tr>
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center">
        <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"></p>
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ra128.infusionsoft.com/app/webTracking/getTrackingCode?trackingId=6a323c394c72471d0866a90788baeed5"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Signature to image page

```
<?php
/**
 *  Signature to Image: A supplemental script for Signature Pad that
 *  generates an image of the signature’s JSON output server-side using PHP.
 *
 *  @project ca.thomasjbradley.applications.signaturetoimage
 *  @author Thomas J Bradley <hey@thomasjbradley.ca>
 *  @link http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-to-image
 *  @link http://github.com/thomasjbradley/signature-to-image
 *  @copyright Copyright MMXI–, Thomas J Bradley
 *  @license New BSD License
 *  @version 1.1.0
 */

/**
 *  Accepts a signature created by signature pad in Json format
 *  Converts it to an image resource
 *  The image resource can then be changed into png, jpg whatever PHP GD supports
 *
 *  To create a nicely anti-aliased graphic the signature is drawn 12 times it's original size then shrunken
 *
 *  @param string|array $json
 *  @param array $options OPTIONAL; the options for image creation
 *    imageSize => array(width, height)
 *    bgColour => array(red, green, blue) | transparent
 *    penWidth => int
 *    penColour => array(red, green, blue)
 *    drawMultiplier => int
 *
 *  @return object
 */
function sigJsonToImage ($json, $options = array()) {
  $defaultOptions = array(
    'imageSize' => array(410, 155)
    ,'bgColour' => array(0xff, 0xff, 0xff)
    ,'penWidth' => 2
    ,'penColour' => array(0x14, 0x53, 0x94)
    ,'drawMultiplier'=> 12
  );

  $options = array_merge($defaultOptions, $options);

  $img = imagecreatetruecolor($options['imageSize'][0] * $options['drawMultiplier'], $options['imageSize'][1] * $options['drawMultiplier']);

  if ($options['bgColour'] == 'transparent') {
    imagesavealpha($img, true);
    $bg = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 127);
  } else {
    $bg = imagecolorallocate($img, $options['bgColour'][0], $options['bgColour'][1], $options['bgColour'][2]);
  }

  $pen = imagecolorallocate($img, $options['penColour'][0], $options['penColour'][1], $options['penColour'][2]);
  imagefill($img, 0, 0, $bg);

  if (is_string($json))
    $json = json_decode(stripslashes($json));

  foreach ($json as $v)
    drawThickLine($img, $v->lx * $options['drawMultiplier'], $v->ly * $options['drawMultiplier'], $v->mx * $options['drawMultiplier'], $v->my * $options['drawMultiplier'], $pen, $options['penWidth'] * ($options['drawMultiplier'] / 2));

  $imgDest = imagecreatetruecolor($options['imageSize'][0], $options['imageSize'][1]);

  if ($options['bgColour'] == 'transparent') {
    imagealphablending($imgDest, false);
    imagesavealpha($imgDest, true);
  }

  imagecopyresampled($imgDest, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $options['imageSize'][0], $options['imageSize'][0], $options['imageSize'][0] * $options['drawMultiplier'], $options['imageSize'][0] * $options['drawMultiplier']);
  imagedestroy($img);

  return $imgDest;
}

/**
 *  Draws a thick line
 *  Changing the thickness of a line using imagesetthickness doesn't produce as nice of result
 *
 *  @param object $img
 *  @param int $startX
 *  @param int $startY
 *  @param int $endX
 *  @param int $endY
 *  @param object $colour
 *  @param int $thickness
 *
 *  @return void
 */
function drawThickLine ($img, $startX, $startY, $endX, $endY, $colour, $thickness) {
  $angle = (atan2(($startY - $endY), ($endX - $startX)));

  $dist_x = $thickness * (sin($angle));
  $dist_y = $thickness * (cos($angle));

  $p1x = ceil(($startX + $dist_x));
  $p1y = ceil(($startY + $dist_y));
  $p2x = ceil(($endX + $dist_x));
  $p2y = ceil(($endY + $dist_y));
  $p3x = ceil(($endX - $dist_x));
  $p3y = ceil(($endY - $dist_y));
  $p4x = ceil(($startX - $dist_x));
  $p4y = ceil(($startY - $dist_y));

  $array = array(0=>$p1x, $p1y, $p2x, $p2y, $p3x, $p3y, $p4x, $p4y);
  imagefilledpolygon($img, $array, (count($array)/2), $colour);
}
```

Final Result of captured image page

```
<?php
require_once 'signature-to-image.php';
$json = $_POST['output'];
$img = sigJsonToImage($json);
imagepng($img, 'signature.png');
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Here is the start page
https://www.protml.com/tmr/sig-confirm.html

And here is where the result ends up
https://www.protml.com/tmr/capture_signature.php

Comment: You call imagepng() twice

Comment: @Lukas the first call is with a second parameter, which means this will save the image to a local file. The second one is without, meaning this call will output the image data to the client. Nothing wrong with that, if one wants to perform both actions at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load this image in the target page using an additional HTTP request (meaning, you want to embed it using `<img src="http://hostname/somescript.php">`), then you need to pass on the data to this `somescript.php`. Now depending on *how much* the user scribbles on the input pad, how many “black pixels” that actually creates, that JSON data can get quite big - probably too big to be put into the query string with a GET request. And since you can not easily load an image using POST in combination with `<img src="...">`, it would probably make most sense to put it into the session then. (In a scenario where you work with customer data, I’d assume you are probably using sessions already anyway.)

So in the script that receives the POST data (different script than `/tmr/capture_signature.php`), you put it into the session,

```
$_SESSION['sigpaddata'] = $_POST['output'];
```

and then in your script that generates the image (`/tmr/capture_signature.php`), you read it back from there (don’t forget to pick up the session again in that script),

```
$json = $_SESSION['sigpaddata'];
```

And then you embed the image on the target page using

```
<img src="/tmr/capture_signature.php">
```

Now this could lead into trouble, if the user has multiple instances of this script open in multiple tabs, to create signatures for multiple receipts. If that is a realistic scenario, you could add a random value to the form, store the JSON data into the session under that random key (`$_SESSION['sigpaddata'][$_POST['randkey']] = …` – you’d have to check if the JS part automatically sends *all* form data, or whether it might need adapting to submit this additional value as well), and then you pass that same random key to the image generating script (`<img src="/tmr/capture_signature.php?randkey=…">`), so that that in turn can fish the right value out of the session again (`$_SESSION['sigpaddata'][$_GET['randkey']]`)

---

A different approach, that doesn’t need an extra HTTP request - and therefor creates a bit less hassle to get the necessary data to the image creating code - would be to output the image “inline” in the target page, using a [Data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) with the base64 encoded image data. That involves output buffering to capture the output of `imagepng` (you are currently saving the image to a file anyway, so you could theoretically read it back from there right after - but then the filename would need to be made unique, using `signature.png` every time for multiple concurrent requests by multiple customers would obviously lead to trouble otherwise.)

```
require_once 'signature-to-image.php';
$json = $_POST['output'];
$img = sigJsonToImage($json);
ob_start(); // start output buffer
imagepng($img); // output image data to buffer
imagedestroy($img);
// create Data URI for a PNG image, using the binary image
// data captured from the output buffer
$dataURI = 'data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode(ob_get_clean());

// echo HTML img element using that Data URI, somewhere on the page
echo '<img src="'.$dataURI.'">';
```

This could be used directly in the response page you are generating based on the form data send from the previous page. Since it doesn’t need an additional HTTP request, the POST data is available directly here, and doesn’t need to be passed on to a different image generating script using a session or anything like that.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you that worked exactly how I wanted it and was very clear and concise. Worked out perfectly. Now I just need to find a way to send the next page as an email so it's frozen in place to the user and myself so it can be kept for record keeping. Thank you again!